# Play song in android in default media player.... i dont want to create my own

Tags: android, controller, media-player

Hi guys 
I want to make a simple application.
It will have one button which when clicked will play the song who's URI is hard coded.
So i basically want the user to click a button and some song will play in the default media player so that i don't have to code for media player buttons.

Is this possible ? do u have a better approach?

this whole situation arises from the problem of fetching album art basically :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service! We expect own attempts from you, so this question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps ya:

```
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();     
    mp.setLooping(true);
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(mFile);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.start();
```

mFile is the path to a mp3-file. maybe you can share an uri instead.

Comment: will this show the album art? i doubt so...

Comment: ok sorry but this is not what i asked for. i want to link a button in my application to the default media player in android which contains the song name , artist name and album art

Comment: Looks like Coxer answered the question you asked to me.

Comment: can i do this with surface view? is there anything called graphics context

Answer (score 0):

Android has a media controller which can bind the media player object. It can be achieved by :

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer()
MediaController mc = new MediaController(mediaPlayer);
mc.setDataSource(Path);
mc.prepare();
mc.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the location of the file you can do something as below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(data);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Here data is your file path. This however opens a lite version of the player. I am myself looking for a better solution but this will do fine for now.